# NameError: name 'ip' is not defined

Tags: java, python

I am getting a syntax error when trying to run the Jython plugin in imageJ.

There is Java that starts with

```
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
public class Invert_Filter implements PlugInFilter {
  public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp) {
    // inform ImageJ that this plugin filter only handles 8 bit grayscale images
    return DOES_8G;
  }
  public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
    // create a Python interpreter
    PythonInterpreter py = new PythonInterpreter();
    // pass the image processor of the current image to the Python interpreter
    py.set("ip", ip);
    // execute the Python file containing the source code for this ImageJ plugin filter
    py.execfile("C:\\ImageJ\\plugins\\Invert_Filter.py");
  }
}
```

And Python code:

```
# "ip" is the image processor of the current image that is passed in from ImageJ
ip.invert()
```

When running this I get:

> NameError: name 'ip' is not defined

Comment: First thing I would do here is to check and see if variable `ip` is null or not.

Comment: Which line is giving that error?

Comment: File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    NameError: name 'ip' is not defined, how do I find out if variable ip is null or not?